# Mounted usb 2.5 inch hdd on pi4 will not go and remain asleep

Tags: linux, debian, external-hard-drive, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a 2.5 inch (no external power) Seagate USB HDD drive connected to the USB3 port of my pi4 with Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster), Kernel: Linux 4.19.97-v7l+.

Using

```
hd-idle -t /dev/sda
```

I am able to spin down the drive when it is not mounted. The device remains asleep.

```
mount /dev/mapper/hdd /mnt/samba2 -o noatime,data=writeback,nobh,errors=continue,relatime,lazytime
```

When the drive is mounted it immediately spins up after the command is issued.

I did not find any active services, that could access and thus wake up the drive.
Please note that the drive is encrypted with LUKS.

Question is:
Why does my mounted drive not go to sleep and remain asleep?
And how can I fix it? Different mounting parameters, is Raspbian the culprit?

Comment: Sorry, what is your question?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey added my question.

Comment: Look [here](https://www.htpcguides.com/spin-down-and-manage-hard-drive-power-on-raspberry-pi/) maybe?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yep, I tried all three tools, only hd-idle works with my drive unmounted. If mounted the spin down is initiated by hd-idle but the drive spins up immediately.